# Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found

Tags: angular, angularjs, npm

I am facing a problem when I try to run ng serve command, but I am getting the following error message:

`Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found.`

I tried npm install  --legacy-peer-deps but I couldn't solve the issue.

The angular.json file can be found at:

https://pastebin.com/h7r6r8Ay

I searched about a solution here on stackoverflow but no success. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing the following line :

```
"defaultProject": "abc"
```

from my `angular.json` file.

defaultProject has been **deprecated**. 
See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11111